# Is this set of functions a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm starting to learn linear algebra am an learning what is and what is not a vector space. I'm trying to figure out if the following set of functions is a vector space:
$\{f : \Bbb R\to\Bbb R | f(3) = 0\}$. I believe it is because it seems to satisfy the $8$ axioms, but I am nervous I am not thinking of a counter example.

Comment: Yes, it is a vector space under the natural operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is. One way to see it is to check the axioms like you did. Another way is to see that $f\rightarrow f(3)$ is a linear application from the vector space of real functions to the real numbers. The set we are looking at is its kernel and is therefore a subspace of the vector space of real functions